# How to indicate $\varepsilon/(h+ik)\rightarrow0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Since it's the first time I study complex function, I'm quite confused of the below sentence  when I read the complex-analysis textbook written by Ahifors. In chapter 2,when he talks about analystic function,he writes:
\begin{equation}
v(x+h,y+k)-v(x,y)=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}h+\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}k+\varepsilon
\end{equation}
where the analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ , $f(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $,$\text{both}\;u(x,y)\;\text{and} \;v(x,y):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

I can understand that $\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\rightarrow0$ when $h\rightarrow0$ and $k\rightarrow0$,how to indicate $\varepsilon/(h+ik)\rightarrow0$

Comment: The first equation is essentially a Taylor series of the function $v$ around the point $(x,y)$. On the right hand side you find the first derivatives with $h$ and $k$ linearly. This means that $\epsilon$ represents all the second and higher terms of the Taylor series expansion. These are of quadratic and higher order in $h$ and $k$. So the division that interests you will indeed tend to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply and divide the expression by the conjugate of $h + ik$ i.e., by $h - ik$. The denominator will form modulus of $h + ik$ and you can use $ε/ (h^2 + K^2)^{1/2}$ tends to $0$ fact to prove the equation.

Comment: Thanks,then to indicate that another part of the equation is bounded,right?And limits equals to zero.